# sql query to show zeros - simple, elegant method

Tags: mysql

I have read answers to similar questions, and solved my problem based on these answers. However the (my) solution is rather complex, it includes two-step views, an additional table with left join. I wonder if there is a simpler, more elegant solution to the problem below as an illustration. The table `Test` has column `B` that needs to be summarized based on a criteria that column `Marker` has values 4 or over. The table `TestResult` is the desired output of the query. As I say, I do have an awkward, complex solution, but I'm curious if there is a simple, elegant method?

```
mysql> select * FROM Test;
+----+------+------+--------+
| ID | A    | B    | Marker |
+----+------+------+--------+
|  1 |   11 |    2 |      4 |
|  2 |   11 |    1 |      5 |
|  3 |   14 |    4 |      4 |
|  4 |   11 |    2 |      1 |
|  5 |   12 |    2 |      2 |
|  6 |   13 |    2 |      3 |
|  7 |   14 |    2 |      2 |
+----+------+------+--------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * FROM TestResult;
+----+------+
| A  | SumB |
+----+------+
| 11 |    3 |
| 12 |    0 |
| 13 |    0 |
| 14 |    4 |
+----+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: There is obvious way for this query. Can you share your query so we would know that we don't have better one?

Comment: Shouldn't 11's sumB be 5?

Comment: @Uueerdo 3rd 11's marker is less than 4.

Comment: @Uueerdo: It looks like straightforward conditional aggregation. I think OP just needs a pattern for doing that.  (Provided in my answer.) For A=11, the SumB value would be 3, from the first two rows in Test.

Comment: Yeah, I misread question overlooking the "or over" part of it.

Comment: Thank you all for suggesting answers. All your answers helped me to learn and better understand the workings of SQL My original, very complicated solution is not worthy of publication, but I can post it if someone is interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it like this.  Start with this:

```
SELECT t.A
  FROM Test t
 GROUP BY t.A
```

That's easy enough.

For the second column, we want a SUM of an expression...

```
SELECT t.A
     , SUM(expr) AS SumB
  FROM Test t
 GROUP BY t.A
```

The trick is to use an expression that does a conditional tests that determine whether a value of column B should be returned or not. For example, in MySQL specific syntax, something like:

```
 IF(t.Marker >= 4, t.B, 0)
```

Or, a more ANSI standards compliant equivalent:

```
 CASE WHEN t.Marker >= 4 THEN t.B ELSE 0 END
```

Putting that all together...

```
SELECT t.A
     , SUM(IF(t.Marker >= 4, t.B, 0)) AS SumB
  FROM Test t
 GROUP BY t.A
```

---

**EDIT**

What if there are rows like this in `Test`

```
+----+------+------+--------+
| ID | A    | B    | Marker |
+----+------+------+--------+
|  1 |   11 |    2 |      4 |
|  2 |   11 |    1 |      5 |
| 17 |   11 |    4 |      1 |
```

I'm questioning whether the row with a Marker value of 1 (which is not greater than or equal to 4), should the value of `B` be included in the SUM?

The query above, you'd get a SumB value of 3. Just the values from first two rows will be included in the SUM.

If you need to return a value of 7 for SumB (including that third row), then you'll need a different query pattern.

Comment: This works for me, and it is simple - thank you Spencer7593. And yes, if the table Test was according to your last version (i.e. only three records), the sumB should still have a value of 3. Obviously, in this case there would be no zero results because A has only a single value of 11.

Answer (score 1):

*Edit: I originally overlooked the "or over" part of the question; leading me to think a different (more difficult to reach) answer was desired. I've corrected the condition, but left the solution for the more difficult answer since someone has apparently found it helpful.*

Using the LEFT JOIN assures you get all A values from Test, the subselect provides you an indicator of the A values of rows satisfying the condition.

```
SELECT A, IF(t1.A IS NULL, 0, SUM(B)) AS sumB
FROM Test AS t0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT A FROM Test WHERE Marker >= 4) AS t1
ON t0.A = t1.A
GROUP BY A;
```

Alternatively, this is the most succinct; but might be less reliable or even rejected through some types of connections.

```
SELECT A, IF(SUM(IF(Marker>=4,1,0))>0, SUM(B),0) AS sumB
FROM Test
GROUP BY A;
```

Comment: Thanks, Uueerdo, but forgive me for my ignorance (I'm a beginner in SQL), the top version does not work, does not return anything. The bottom, "most succinct" version returns wrong results (5 for 11 and 6 for 14) - and I don't understand why, because it is a clever method. I tried to take out the first SUM() function, and the result is the same.

Comment: As stated in my edit, these will not return the results you are looking for; but both should return the same results (which should in include all A values). It could be that I needed to specify `t0.A` in the first field of the `SELECT` and in the `GROUP BY` on that first query.

Comment: @Janos _I had thought you wanted the total B values for A values that had Marker values >= 4, not the total of B values that had Marker values >= 4 by grouped by their A values_

Answer (score 1):

Could be achieved by using `group by` and `case`:

```
select A, sum(case when marker >= 4 then B else 0 end)
  from Test 
 group by A;
```

Check out this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d01f0/6)

Comment: He wants sum of all B for A that have any marker = 4; not sum of marker 4 B values.

Comment: That is exactly what the query does. Check the Fiddle and compare it to the desired result above. The `case` function above takes care that any B values are set to `0`, whenever the marker is `< 4`

Comment: @Uueerdo: I understand what you are saying. But wouldn't that mean that the fourth row shown in OP result (for A=14) have a SumB value of 6 and not 4 if that were true?

Comment: @spencer7593 Yeah, but then A=11's sumB should be 2. (Since it makes no sense either way that it is 3, I just asked for clarification above.)

Comment: @Uueerdo: Row ID=1 and ID=2 both satisfy the criteria A=11 and Marker>=4. And that gives a SumB value of 3. But it looks like row ID=4 is excluded (because Marker = 1), so the B value is not included in the SUM.  Looks like a straightforward conditional aggregation to me.

Comment: @Uueerdo: why not? Add columns with ID 1 and 2, because markers in these rows have a value of 4 or higher ....

Comment: @spencer7593 Oh, my mistake, I overlooked the "or over" part of the question.